# In Magento 2, can I have a per item shipping cost of $1, but only for items from a specific category?

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

I know I can set a rule to set the shipping to free.
I know I can set a table rate for the whole site.

I want to keep my regular table rate for most products which is a weight based table.  What I would like to find is a way to charge $1 in shipping for any Greeting card purchased, and have that as a choice on the checkout screen as well.

This way, if a customer buys a windchime and a card, the weight of the card would essentially be free for shipping purposes.

If that same customer only buys a card, they have the option of only paying $1 for shipping.